# Invoke azcopy from azure function

Tags: azure-functions

Looking for execute azcopy from azure function. checked possibilities that azure function with powershell script function may helps here. But powershell is experimental support only. my question is Is there any other way to do with azure function.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell on Azure Functions **v2** and **v3** is *fully supported*, it is *not* experimental. PowerShell support on Functions **v1** is experimental.

Comment: Agree. But functions are in v1. planned for go with Azure Storage Data Movement Library which gives azcopy implementation in programmatic way.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/

Comment: @mano Are you able solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Azure.Storage.Blob Nuget Pack Using "**StartCopyFromUriAsync**" method

Refer the link [here](https://build5nines.com/azure-functions-copy-blob-between-azure-storage-accounts-in-c/)

Reference doc from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)

Answer (score 0):

Azure.Storage.Blob will have a file size limit of 2GB. For larger files azcopy maybe the answer.